# Can we get "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" error if the user is not able to log into the DB?

Tags: oracle

My application is giving the "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" error when in prod environment. Locally it works just fine(when tested locally I am accessing staging DB). On checking the DB in prod I found tables to be there but we have still not populated the values.

Comment: Only when you get into a room , you can say someone is not there :) Same here! Perhaps, the table do exists in a different schema. Try to access it using schema.tablename.

Comment: There are (if the table is there) a few causes: a) you log in to wrong user, wrong database (tenant) or have the wrong default schema (search), wrong edition or fine grained access cotnrol.. But there are also oracle bugs around cached statements leading to not found tables when they are there (mostly with exotic data like blob). I have seen them fixed in 11.2.0.4.10 (and others). You can actually trace the ORA-942, it will give you a hint: `ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '942 trace name context forever, level 8';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, no. You cannot receive an `ORA-00942` if you are not even connected to the database.
To address your further comments it is probably a matter of properly identifying the table and schema it is in.

```
conn system/manager;
grant select on hr.employees to scott;
conn scott/scott;
select * from employees;
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
select * from hr.employees;
<return data>
```

Alternatively you can create a synonym for the table in the `scott` schema:

```
create or replace synonym scott.employees for hr.employees;
```

This will allow the failed query to succeed as the `scott` schema has an object called `employees` in its scope.

Comment: What if the table is accessed by a schema owner?

Should it still have to address table as <owner>.employees  ?

Comment: If the table is accessed by the schema owner then it is not necessary to qualify the table call. So if `emp` is owned by `hr` then `hr` could execute `select * from emp;` without issue.

Comment: ... unless you set a different default schema (in session or by a login trigger).

Comment: This is true as well. There is definitely more than one way to skin this cat.